# Pentaho Transpose column to rows

Tags: sql, pentaho

I have this table in Pentaho.

```
YYYYMM  Value   Counts

201701  InSTOCK   10
201702  InSTOCK   5
201703  InSTOCK   2
201704  InSTOCK   4
201702  newstock  4
201703  newstock  8
201704  newstock  8
201701  reserve   3
201702  reserve   3
```

I would like to have my data like this

```
 YYYYMM   InSTOCK   newstock  reserve
 201701    10                   3
 201702    5          4         3
 201703    2          8
 201704    4          8
```

Is there a way to unpivot like this with Pentaho or perhaps a SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use SQL or Pentaho. With Pentaho you use the step **Row denormaliser**.

To use the Row denormaliser, you need to previously sort your rows by the columns you use to group your unpivot operation. In the operator, you define the **group columns**, the **key column** to perform the unpivot, and the new columns:

- **Target fieldname** is the name of the new column
- **Value fieldname** is the name of the incoming column you use to fill this Target fieldname
- **Key value** is the value that the Key field (column) you selected above to perform the unpivot. In your example Key value and Target fieldname have the same values, but you could define a different column name for your values.

[image: Transformation example]